# Dynamic Range in VBA offest issues

Tags: excel, vba

tried many examples and followed many videos but no luck please help
I am trying to create a dynamic range starting at E2

try 1

```
Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range("E2:E10")
```

try 2

```
Set StatusCol = OFFSET(Sheet1!$E$2,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!E2:E500),1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set statuscol = Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & Sheet1.cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).row)
```

You can then run `statuscol.select` to make sure your desired range is selected

Note: the `1` assumes you have data in every row of column 1 (A). change it to a different column number if that is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use built in excel function to vba then have to use ***Application.WorkSheetFunction*** method. Otherwise can try below sub.

```
Sub TillLastCol()
Dim StatusCol As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim lr As Long

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lr = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set StatusCol = sh.Range("E2:E" & lr)
    'Debug.Print StatusCol.Address
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Reference Dynamic One-Column Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReferenceColumnRangeSHORT()
' No Constants
' No With Statement
' Ultra Short Message
' One Variable

    ' Reference the one-column range ('StatusCol').
    Dim StatusCol As Range: Set StatusCol _
        = Sheet1.Range("E2", Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp))

    ' Continue using 'StatusCol'...

    ' Inform using the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
    Debug.Print StatusCol.Address(0, 0)
    ' Inform using a message box.
    MsgBox StatusCol.Address(0, 0), vbInformation, _
        "Reference Dynamic One-Column Range"

End Sub

Sub ReferenceColumnRange()
' No Constants
' No With Statement
' Short Message

    ' Reference the first cell ('FirstCell').
    Dim FirstCell As Range: Set FirstCell = Sheet1.Range("E2")
    ' Reference the last cell ('LastCell').
    Dim LastCell As Range
    Set LastCell = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, FirstCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    ' Reference the one-column range ('StatusCol').
    Dim StatusCol As Range: Set StatusCol = Sheet1.Range(FirstCell, LastCell)

    ' Continue using 'StatusCol'...

    ' Store a message in a string variable.
    Dim MsgString As String: MsgString = _
        "The Status column range's address is '" _
        & StatusCol.Address(0, 0) & "'."
    
    ' Inform using the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
    Debug.Print MsgString
    ' Inform using a message box.
    MsgBox MsgString, vbInformation, "Reference Dynamic One-Column Range"

End Sub

Sub ReferenceColumnRangeEDU()

' What you know:
'     1.) The worksheet is in the workbook containing this code
'         and its code name is 'Sheet1'.
'     2.) The first (top-most) cell of your one-column range is cell 'E2'.
'     3.) Your range variable's name will be 'StatusCol'
' What you don't know:
'     1.) How to reference the last (bottom-most) non-empty cell
'         in column 'E'?
'     2.) How to reference the range from the first to the last cell?

    ' Store the address of the first cell
    ' in a constant string variable ('FirstCellAddress').
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "E2"
    
    ' Declare the range variables.
    Dim StatusCol As Range
    Dim FirstCell As Range
    Dim LastCell As Range
    
    ' Using the With statement, reference the worksheet
    ' by its code name ('Sheet1').
    With Sheet1
        ' Reference the first cell ('FirstCell').
        Set FirstCell = .Range(FirstCellAddress)
        ' Reference the last cell ('LastCell').
        Set LastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, FirstCell.Column).End(xlUp)
        ' Reference the one-column range ('StatusCol').
        Set StatusCol = .Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
    End With

    ' Continue using 'StatusCol'...

    ' Store some stats in a string variable.
    Dim MsgString As String: MsgString = vbLf & "Stats" & vbLf & vbLf & _
        "The Status column range's address is '" _
        & StatusCol.Address(0, 0) & "'." & vbLf _
        & "It is located in the worksheet '" & Sheet1.Name & "' (tab name)." _
        & vbLf & "The worksheet is located in the workbook (file) '" _
        & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'." & vbLf _
        & "The file is located in the folder '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "'."
    
    ' Inform using the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G').
    Debug.Print MsgString
    
    ' Inform using a message box.
    MsgBox MsgString, vbInformation, "Reference Dynamic One-Column Range"

End Sub
```